# Accessing VirtualBox Visual Studio project from Mac

Tags: asp.net, networking, localhost, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have a Windows guest instance in VirtualBox, which is running a Visual Studio ASP.NET project on localhost server. I'd like to be able to access the project's running server from a web browser on the host computer (a Mac).

I've been told to set the network settings of the virtual machine to Bridged Adapter, however this is not working. Is there some other setting I'm missing?

Comment: VirtualBox can share directories between the host and guest, but the guest needs to have the Guest Additions installed. Google is your friend.

Comment: @Pali Apologies if I was unclear - I want to access the localhost server running on the VM, from the host machine. Not the project files themselves. Edited the question for clarification.

Comment: In VirtuelBox edit your VM Settings, go to Network and click port forwarding (can'r remember the right text of this button), there you can map host ports to guest ports (e.g. host port 80 to guest port 80 so you can simply open your web server from your host browser at http://localhost/

Comment: @Pali Port Forwarding is only available when the network is set to NAT, which is contrary to the recommended setting of Bridged Adapter in this situation...?

Comment: What is preventing you to switch back to NAT?

Comment: Otherwise find out the IP of your VM and access your server by its IP ...

Comment: @Pali, OK, I ran ipconfig on the guest and retrieved the IP address. I then changed network to NAT, enabled port forwarding from host to guest, and entered the IP address in the host browser. The ASP.NET project is unfortunately not appearing in the browser

Comment: check if your guest firewall blocks port 80, check if your web server is listening on port 80 or on another port. Both port forwarding AND accessing it with the IP does not work since port forwarding binds the port to the VM